# Line chart with very small difference in values

Tags: charts, microsoft-excel-2010

I have data in excel that basically looks something like this:

```
x264    VP8     Theora
0.99593 0.99328 0.96688
0.99497 0.99243 0.96646
0.99442 0.99180 0.96680
   .............
and so on for about 4500 lines
```

The values are all between 0.95 and 0.99. Now I have a problem since Excel keeps drawing the Y axis (values) with scale from 0.0 to 1.0 and (it seems) rounds all the data simply to 1.0, thus I just get a straight line.

How could I do a comparative line plot of this data in range from 0.95 to 1.0?

Comment: How are you creating the chart? What sort of chart are you making?

Answer (score 1):

- Right-click on the y-axis and select **Format Axis...**
- On the **Axis Options** tab change Minimum and Maximum to **Fixed** and supply the values you want (0.95 and 0.99)
- You can optionally set the major and minor units if you don't like Excel's choices.

Comment: I did do that, however the line remains flat even after I set axis limits to those values.

Comment: @Mavrik, you should probably check your data and make sure it is numeric. If it has been imported from somewhere else it may have been imported as text rather than numbers, which might cause the problem you're having. Try applying different number format to the data (eg. increase the number of decimal places). If nothing happens to your data's appearance then it is probably text, not numeric.

Answer (score -1):

You could try multiply your data by 1000 or so and then at Y axis options change it to [Thousands](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T7dFS.jpg) and delete [Unit Label](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6VMod.jpg).